# React.memo not working for functional component. if the feature ain't supported as i have seen , what is the other way to optimize?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, rendering

Child Component using React.memo

but the code isn't working as expected since there is no effect of using React.memo

```
import React,{ useEffect } from 'react';
import Pit from './Cockpit.module.css';


const Cockpit = (attri) => {
  useEffect(() => {

  console.log("[Cockpit.js] rendering")

    const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
      alert("Hi");
    },1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer)
      console.log("hi")
    }
  });


let Classes=[];
if(attri.personArrayLength<=2){
  Classes.push(Pit.red)
}
if(attri.personArrayLength<=1){
  Classes.push(Pit.italic)
}
console.log(Classes)

let btnClass = '';
if(attri.personFlag)
btnClass=Pit.Red;



return (
    <div className={Pit.Cockpit}>
    <h1>{attri.title}</h1>
    <h2 className={Classes.join(' ')}>Next will be Next.js with Node.js</h2>
    <button
    onClick={attri.toggle}
    className={btnClass}
    >Click Me!!!
    </button>
    </div>
    )
};

export default React.memo(Cockpit);
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: `Classes` should be a state.